# Function not defined....My Function Call is not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with this code. I keep getting the error changeBG is not defined.

The way the code should work is when I select a radio button the background changes. If I change the function to an inline function inside the onclick event then it works but if I move the funtion to script section it doesn't work for example:
`<input type="radio" id="red" name="change1" value=1 onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor='red'" /><label for="red">Red</label><br />`
WORKS at changing the background red

but when I make a function in the script section and call the function in the onlick event it doesn't work,

Example of code that is not working:

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
  function changeBG(n)       
  {
    if (n==1)
        document.body.style.backgroundColor='red'";
    if (n==2)
        document.body.style.backgroundColor='yellow'";
    if (n==3)
        document.body.style.backgroundColor='green'";
    if (n==4)
        document.body.style.backgroundColor='orange'";      
  }
  </script>
```

HTML:

```
     <form id="jp2" name="jp2" method="get">                                                                          
        <input type="radio" id="red" name="change1" value=1 onclick="changeBG(1)" />
        <label for="red">Red</label><br />
        <input type="radio" id="Yellow" name="change1" value=2 onclick="changeBG(2)" />
        <label for="yellow">Yellow</label><br />
        <input type="radio" id="Green" name="change1" value=3 onclick="changeBG(3)"  />
        <label for="green">Green</label><br />
        <input type="radio" id="Orange" name="change1" value=4  onclick="changeBG(4)" />
        <label for="orange">Orange</label><br />
     </form>
```

Comment: Where in the page is your script? And why do your colors have double quotes at the end? `'red'"`. Seems to work fine if you fix that and load the script in the right place http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nnn3jmjc/

Comment: Is the script in a separate JS file? If so, you don't need the `<script>` tags.

Comment: The function has syntax errors in it. Remove the `"`s at the end of each `document.body.style` line

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Answer (score 3):

```
backgroundColor='red'"
backgroundColor='yellow'"
backgroundColor='green'"
backgroundColor='orange'"
```

You see those extra `"` quotemarks? Get rid of them.

[**Your working code**](http://jsfiddle.net/11hg1dLe/3/)

In Firefox this gives the following console error. You should learn how to do some simple debugging so you can catch these errors early.

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Answer (score 0):

Use proper quotes. You had used wrong extra quotes. like `''"`. Since these extra quote made JS error, you are error i.e. function not defined.

Change js to following.

```js
 function changeBG(n) {
   if (n == 1)
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   if (n == 2)
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
   if (n == 3)
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
   if (n == 4)
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
 }
```

```html
<form id="jp2" name="jp2" method="get">
  <input type="radio" id="red" name="change1" value=1 onclick="changeBG(1)" />
  <label for="red">Red</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" id="Yellow" name="change1" value=2 onclick="changeBG(2)" />
  <label for="yellow">Yellow</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" id="Green" name="change1" value=3 onclick="changeBG(3)" />
  <label for="green">Green</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" id="Orange" name="change1" value=4 onclick="changeBG(4)" />
  <label for="orange">Orange</label>
  <br />
</form>
```